# Finding the best cosine similarity in a set of vectors

Tags: algorithm, math, cosine-similarity

I have n vectors, each with m elements (real number). I want to find the pair where there cosine similarity is maximum among all pairs.

The straightforward solution would require O(n<sup>2</sup>m) time.

Is there any better solution?

**update**

[Cosine similarity / distance and triangle equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102924/cosine-similarity-distance-and-triangle-equation) Inspires me that I could replace "cosine similarity" with "chord length" which
 loses precision but increases speed a lot. ( there are many existing solutions solving Nearest Neighbor in metric space, like [ANN](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/) )

Comment: @hs3180 Are there any restrictions on the elements of your vectors?  E.g. are they always binary (0 or 1)?

Comment: @robmayoff No, elements are real ( float )

Comment: @robmayoff If elements are binary, this problem is equivalent to find a pair of 01 strings that have the most same bits .

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Cosine similarity `sim(a,b)` is [related to Euclidean distance](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring12/cos598C/SVDforclustering.pdf) `|a - b|` by

```
|a - b|² = 2(1 - sim(a,b))
```

for unit vectors `a` and `b`.

That means cosine similarity is greatest when Euclidean distance is smallest after normalizing by the L2 norm, and the problem reduces to the [closest pair of points problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem), which can be solved in O(n lg n) time.

Comment: Great answer! Giving a clear relationship between Cosine similarity and Euclidean distance.

Comment: beautiful answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the project simbase https://github.com/guokr/simbase , it is a vector similarity nosql database.

Simbase use below concepts:

- Vector set: a set of vectors
- Basis: the basis for vectors, vectors in one vector set have same basis
- Recommendation: a one-direction binary relationship between two vector sets which have the same basis

You can use redis-cli directly for administration tasks, or you can use redis client bindings in different language directly in a programming way. Here is a Python example

```
    import redis

    dest = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=7654)
    schema = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    dest.execute_command('bmk', 'ba', *schema)
    dest.execute_command('vmk', 'ba', 'va')
    dest.execute_command('rmk', 'va', 'va', 'cosinesq')
```