# K-means text documents clustering. How calculate intra and inner similarity?

Tags: text, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I classify thousands of documents where the vector components are calculated according to the tf-idf. I use the cosine similarity. I did a frequency analysis of words in clusters to check the difference in top words. But I'm not sure how to calculate the similarity numerically in this sort of documents.

I count internal similarity of a cluster as the average of the similarity of each document to the centroid of the cluster. If I counted the average couple is based on small number.

External similarity calculated as the average similarity of all pairs cluster centroid

I count right? It is based on my inner similarity values average ​​from 0.2 (5 clusters and 2000 documents)to 0.35 (20 clusters and 2000 documents). Which is probably caused by a widely-oriented documents in computer science. Intra from 0.3-0.7. The result may be like that? On the Internet I found various ways of measuring, do not know which one to use than the one that was my idea. I am quite desperate.

Thank you so much for your advice!

Comment: *k*-means uses Euclidean distance, not a similarity score.

Comment: @larsmans still it works well with other distance metrics as well, e.G. the cosine distance.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut: or L1 distance, but only if you take medians instead of means. The reason why it works with cosine distance is probably because that's a [trivial transformation of Euclidean distance](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13662112/166749).

Answer (score 1):

Using k-means with anything but squared euclidean is risky. It may stop converging, as the convergence proof relies on both the *mean* and the distance assignment optimizing the same criterion. **K-means minimizes squared deviations, not distances**!

For a k-means variant that can handle **arbitrary distance functions** (and have guaranteed convergence), you will need to look at **k-medoids**.

Comment: If I reprezent all document only in 1. quadrant. Can I use cosine similarity. For a small count of the document, I get everything debugoval and the results came out as they shouldFor small documents.Medoid They have already attacked me but I do not think I have a solution wrong.

Comment: I don't know of a proof that k-means always converges with cosine distance. Does cosine distance minimize the sum of squares? Probably not.